# Opentest_cli not recognize STAF process when execute from Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, opentest, staf

All,

I am starting the Jenkins agent and STAF process via Crontab at my Ubuntu 14.04. When I executing opentest_cli through Jenkins job that should connect to the STAF process it says that the STAF process not alive although I see the STAF process at "ps -ef". Any idea why?

Thanks to all for helping

Comment: the base is log from action. what is reported on them?

Comment: @Znik, this message from Jenkins log "Making sure session is not alive!", nothing from STAF ( ~/staf/data/STAF/tmp/ ).